# SQL Delete taking too long

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

We have a table(say T1) that is referenced by about 16 other tables with foreign keys in our SQL Server database. The data is accessed through an ASP.NET application with LINQToSQL. When the user tried to delete a record from T1 the statement would time out. So we decided to first delete the records from the tables that reference T1 and only then delete the record in T1. The problem is that deletion from T1 does not work as fast as expected.

My question is: is it normal that deletion from a table referenced by many other tables to be so time-consuming even if the record itself does not have any 'children' records?

EDIT: Apparently the cause for the timeout was not the delete itself but another query that retrieved data from the same DataContext. Thank you for your suggestions, I have marked as answer the suggestion to add indexes for all foreign keys because it improved our script's execution plan.

Comment: You should attempt to run a query analyzer on the delete statement.  Most SQL Server implementations contain a profiler that will show you the execution plan and you can identify the bottleneck directly rather than asking people to speculate on whether or not the speed is "normal" which is a very subjective, vague term.

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Profiler to see what is happening during these calls?  You can grab the SQL and then run an execution plan and see where your delay is.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your foreign keys? See this old chestnut: http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2006/01/slow-sql-server-delete.html

Comment: @g.d.d.c I have checked the execution plan: it does check for child records and executes a delete statement for each table; but on SQL server this runs instantly; but when I run the 'DELETE FROM T1...' statement from C# it takes much longer and the script sometimes times out

Comment: @George: the SQL statement that takes a long time is 'delete from T1 where MarkedAsDeleted=1'; the execution plan is a huge beast :D

Comment: @James McCormack: I think we have a foreign key on all children, but I'm not sure we have one for each table, I will have to check; thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you may need to look into the indexing on your child tables.

It sounds as if you FKs are set to Cascade Deletes, so I would suspect that some of your tables do not have an index that includes the key to the parent as the first in the index.

In this way your delete will be full scanning the child tables - even if you've already deleted the child records it will still check as you've still got the Cascade set.

Comment: You're right, it does scan all the child tables...I have checked the execution plan and after checking if it has child records in a table it executes a delete statement for each table. So do you think that replacing the cascade with no action would reduce the execution time considerably or not?

Comment: Not really as you still hqve to do the deletes on way or other. Look at the execution plan for the deletes to see jow they are seeking and check your indexes.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a relationship in DB, you can set the `Delete rule` as `Cascade` in SQL server. In this way, when you delete the record from the parent table, it will be automatically deleted from the child tables.

Please see the image below:

[image]

> If it taking long time, you may have set other constraint that will slow
>   down the process of deletion.

Comment: From the question is sounds like they have got this set already.

Comment: If he use linq-to-SQL and set the relation properly, Upon submitting changes, child record should be deleted.

Comment: The problem is that the table already uses cascading and I suppose that it is one of the reasons why deletion takes so long. We deleted all the 'children' first so that they wouldn't have to be deleted by the cascade mechanism. Apparently this wasn't such a good solution :D

Comment: Yes, but what he's saying it that this is taking too long - that implies that he is doing the cascade (in some manner). If he's not cascading he should immediately get FK violations, not Timeouts

Comment: @loana; you must have some other problem like, you may have set other constraint, that may slow the process.

Answer (score 1):

Linq does not do bulk deletes if you're having it operate directly on the record set -- instead, it is probably deleting **one record at a time**.

To improve performance, use a stored procedure instead for any bulk insert, update or delete operations.

Comment: I have not used the LINQ delete, instead I am running an SQL delete statement.

Comment: You mean Linq is not involved with the delete statement in any way?  How are you doing it then -- with a SQLcommand object, or something else?  Have you tried using a stored procedure instead?